# How to show the dateLable in SVPullToRefresh

Tags: iphone, object, tableview

when I use the `SVPullToRefresh` ,I try set  `self.showsDateLabel = YES;` but it did not work.
the `dateLable` shows nothing! Anyone knows how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

On the first look at headers i see this

```
// deprecated; use setSubtitle:forState: instead
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) UILabel *dateLabel DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE;
```